# Can We change an Endpoint in Wso2Esb dynamically

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

while we implementing proxy services we can define endpoint. It was working in local system
we need to change the Production Environment or deployment or testing .In this Case I need to change my endpoint Address if My Wso2dss server in another machine that time local host not working so.i need overcome this .you have any reference for this which will set every endpoint as property whenever i need to change Environment no need set a Con fig file if change in property it will reflect every where

Answer (score 1):

The only way is, to use [Header](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Header+Mediator) mediator to set "To" address dynamically. You can use Header mediator to set "To" addressing header and after that use the "Default" endpoint to send the request. Message will be send to the address, which is set by the "To" header.
To set value, in Header mediator dynamically , you can use xpath, where you can pick a predefined property or do an xpath evaluation for the incoming request to pick the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic endpoints.So you store your endpoints in your registry and refer them. Please refer this [sample](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+10%3a+Introduction+to+Dynamic+Endpoints+with+the+Registry).

Comment: thanx a lot shelan where i can find this registry files in /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/endpoints here only we are getting defined endpoints only not showing dynamic endpoint files

Comment: You can store them in the embedded registry inside ESB ( or use external governace registry with mounted). http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Storing+Various+WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus+Configurations , http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html